# how to loop through rows depending on time

Tags: php

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

```
 table schedule

ID  |  stud_id| day    | timein   | timeout
 1  | 8888    | Monday | 08:00AM  | 09:00AM 
 2  | 8888    | Monday | 10:00AM  | 12:00PM 
 3  | 8888    | Monday | 01:00PM  | 03:00PM 
 4  | 8888    | Tuesday| 05:00PM  | 07:00PM
```

php code is given below:

```
<?php

$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM schedule where day = Monday and stud_id = 8888")or die(mysql_error());
  $i = 0;
  $time = strtotime(date('h:iA'));
 while($row = $query->fetchall()){
  $count = $query->rowcount();
if($count > 0){
$timein = $row[$i]['timein'];
$timeout = strtotime($row[$i]['timeout']);
           }
  if($time > $timeout){ //example time is 09:50am
         $i++;
         $timein; 
         $timeout;  
                      }
     echo $timein, $timeout;
```

this should be good because it will output the second row, but when the time is 12:50PM it still echo the second row even though it should echo the third row, I know my syntax is not correct, I just dont know how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't correct in many ways:

1- `$query->fetchAll()` shouldn't be used inside `while` condition, instead you have to define a variable which will contain the query result then iterate through it using `for` or `foreach`. For example, `$result = $query->fetchAll();`

2- The code inside `while` loop will print `$timein` and `$timeout` no matter what because the conditions you wrote doesn't stop the execution of this line `echo $timein, $timeout;`

3- Why did you use `$query->rowcount()`? It contains the total rows in the result array. So if you want to use it, it has to be before the loop not inside it.

4- These two lines `$timein; $timeout;` doesn't perform any logical operation, it has no use here.

Here's a correct approach:

```
<?php
$query= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM schedule where day = Monday and stud_id = 8888") or die(mysql_error());
$time = strtotime(date('h:iA'));
$result = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $timein = $row['timein'];
    $timeout = strtotime($row['timeout']);
    if ($time > $timeout)
    { 
        continue;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $timein;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to start in the first row, it starts in the second row even without the if statement. and it doesnt go to the third row if the time is greater than the timeout

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what is the purpose of your code. Do you want it to print only one row if the timeout in it is greater than the current time or any row in which the timeout is greater than the current time?

Comment: sorry, example when the time < row[0]timeout then row[0]timein , if time is > row[0]timeout then row[1]timein, and so forth,

Comment: I want it to start on the first row unless the time is greater than the first row ['timeout']

Comment: What is the expected output for the whole loop? timein for all the rows which this condition applies `time < $row['timeout']` or only the next valid row?

Comment: start on first row, then if time is greater than the first row timeout go second row, if time is greater than second row timeout, go third row and so forth, if time is greater than last row timeout then  echo 'no schedule'

Comment: I updated the answer. If time is less than timeout on the second row, it will print timein for the second row and then go to the third row and print timein if the time is still less than timeout or skip if the time is greater than timeout and so on. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want it to start on the first row sir ($timein =$row[0]timein,  $timeout[0]timeout) but if the time is greater than $row[0]timeout then it will go to the second row($timein = $row[1]timein , $timeout = $row[1]timeout , if time > $row[1]timeout then go to 3rd row ($row[2]timein , $row[2]timeout, I want it to start in the first row unless the time is greater than the $row[0]timeout , sorry sir if the explanation is not clear,

Comment: The current code is supposed to do what you've described, did you try it? If yes, provide the output of `print_r($result);` to see the result of the sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the timein, timeout fields should be stored as time in the database (for example "08:00:00" instead of "08:00AM"

Also there was a missing } in the end

This works if you do the change in your database:

```
<?php
$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM schedule where day = Monday and stud_id = 8888")or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$localtime = "12:50:00";
$time = strtotime($localtime);
while($row = $query->fetchall()){
  $count = $query->rowcount();
  if($count > 0){
    $timein = $row[$i]['timein'];
    $timeout = strtotime($row[$i]['timeout']);
  }
  if($time > $timeout){ //example time is 09:50am
    $i++;
    $timein; 
    $timeout;  
  }
}
echo $timein." - ".$timeout."<br/>";
?>
```